# Placing JButton in upper right

Tags: java, swing, layout, jbutton

I want to place a `JButton` in the upper right corner of a `JPanel`. Currently, using `BorderLayout`, it is in the right, but the layout stretches the button. This is what I'm talking about:

[image]

What layout could I use to easily fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the button into a panel with another layout such as a `GridBagLayout` and then place this panel into the `BorderLayout.EAST` section like you were doing before.

Answer (score 1):

- Create another `JPanel`
- Add the `JButton` to this panel
- Add the panel to the `WEST` position of the container

Answer (score 1):

You should use [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) and put the button in the third column, first row. Then make the other components grow or use more columns.

Read the documentation. GridBagLayout may be a bit difficult to understand but is the most flexible layout. Any other solution requires to use panels inside panels.

PS: Also, first answer talks about GridBagLayout, but BorderLayout.EAST is a constant from the BorderLayout

Comment: His answer works perfectly, but I believe yours would too. His is just easier :) Also, I think he meant place the `JPanel` that had the other layout (with the button) *inside* the main panel at `EAST`.

Comment: you are right.. but it was confusing. But you should investigate GridBagLayout. It is very flexible and provide more control :D